# Vue webpack-simple error while installing

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, vue-component

when i'm run webpack-simple cli the terminal showing this error for me ,  please how can i solve it?

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/vue-cli/node_modules/deep-extend/lib/deep-extend.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) {

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/vue-cli/node_modules/rc/index.js:4:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
➜  ~
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure that you have the latest version of `vue-cli` and `node.js`

**Update vue-cli:**
`npm update vue-cli --save -g`

**Update npm version:** 
`npm install npm@latest -g`

After that try again write down this line:

`vue init webpack-simple my-project`

If it won't help try remove all your global `node_modules` folder and install again.

Comment: thanks i totally removed npm folder then i reinstall node again and it works but i faced issue with wepback-simple
 Failed to download repo vuejs-templates/wepback-simple but when i initialize wepback it works fine , how can i init wepback-simple